# How to sign out github account in vs code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

In VS code, I am signed in with a github account in which I have no longer my access. So I need to completely unlink the github account from vs code. How can I do that? I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find this button at the bottom left corner:[image]

Comment: The option to sign out is now gone as of April 2022 from this menu.

Comment: So it is. 1.66.2 is missing the profile icon. Now what?

Answer (score 3):

Answer for VS Code version `1.76.2`.

I was only able to sign out of my Github account by totally uninstalling Visual Studio Code and reinstalling it. It was a very quick process as I first made copies of (I'm on a mac):
`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`
`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
and all extensions in
`~/.vscode/extensions`

The reason I needed this was I signed up for GitHub Copilot and was getting the error

> Your GitHub token is invalid. Please sign out from your GitHub account using VSCode UI and try again.

but I could not figure out how to do this. I tried deleting all caches and anything with the name Github in it in:
`~/Library/Application Support/Code`
`~/.vscode`
but still this did not work and I had to resort to the nuclear option stated above.

After the fresh install I was successfully disconnected from my Github account and I was then able to get Copilot to authenticate correctly by signing in fresh to my Github account.

Comment: Thanks BigHeadCreations! This was my solution. Sad that it is not a priority to allow switching of accounts :-|